Moment calculation about levers with exxtensions
I am looking to calculate the moment about levers across various shapes where parts of it's body can contact the rope applying tension and change the geometry.
Scenario 1:

The lever of length $d$ on the left is without any extension while the lever on the right has an extension of length $l$.
The purple circle is the pivot point.
The red line represents a rope with a force of $F$ being applied on the ends so should have an equivalent tension along it's length.
The rope is tied at the end of the lever where the red line originates in the diagram.
For both levers, the moment calculation should be as follows.
$$M = F \times d $$
Scenario 2:

Left:
$$
M = F \times d\cos{\theta}
$$
This is the part I'm not sure about. This is what I think the moment should be.
Right:
$$
M = F \times d\cos{\theta} + F \times l\sin{\theta}
$$
Here the force is divided into it's x and y components and acts on their respective perpendicular directions.
Scenario 3:

Left moment should be zero.
Right:
$$M = F \times l$$
Scenario 4:

$$
M = - F \times d\cos{\theta} + F \times l\sin{\theta}
$$
For scenarios 1-3, the rotation will be clockwise. I'm not sure what direction the lever will move for scenario 4.
Maybe there is a simulation software that is available that can simulate such scenarios so I can check my work?
If I wanted to apply a constant moment on the pivot point, would equal length lever rods, $d = l$, provide a constant torque? Is there any geometry, besides a disc, be able to do that?
Context: This is not a homework as provided from any institution. I've never encountered a system during my formal education where the contact point of the force on a lever arm can change. I am trying to math it out for a hobby project where I need a way to keep the moment as unchanged as possible where the the tension generating device does not change position by the rope connection point changes as the lever rotates.

Why do you not use the vector product $M=\vec{F}\times \vec{r}$,  $\vec{r}$ the vector to the pivot, Than all the problems are clear.

It's actually the reverse. R vector cross F vector
